# How do I replace the old schemas with the new edit ones?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I have schemas like this:

```js
{ user: '123', code: 'abc', uses: [...] },
{ user: '123', code: 'def', uses: [...] },
```

and I want it like this:

```js
{ user: '123', code: ['abc', 'def'], uses: [...] },
```

I'm currently trying with this

```js
schema.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$uses' },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id', user: { $first: '$user' }, code: { $addToSet: '$code' }, uses: { $addToSet: '$uses' } } }
  ]);
```

but I don't get the result that I want, It do not change anything, beside the fact that now `code` is an array but with only 1 code.

Basically I edided the way how a func work and now I need `code` to be an array, and since I have over 400 documents I'm trying to edit all this documents to fit the new function w/o doing it by hand.

EDIT: Ok I think I make it work with

```js
{ $unwind: '$uses' },
{ $group: { _id: '$user', code: { $addToSet: '$code' }, uses: { $addToSet: '$uses' } } }
```

the problem (i think) was `user: { $first: '$user' }` because now w/o it it work like I want. But now the problem is another. How do I replace the old schemas with the new ones?

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question or edit the word "solved" into the title. To mark it "solved", post the answer in the "Your Answer" field below, and mark the answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working code:

```js
const invites = await schema.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$uses' },
    { $group: { _id: '$user', code: { $addToSet: '$code' }, uses: { $addToSet: '$uses' } } }
]);

for (const invite of invites) {
    await schema.deleteMany(
      {
        user: invite._id
      }
    );
    
    await new schema(
      {
        user: invite._id,
        code: invite.code,
        uses: invite.uses
      }
    ).save();
};
```

As I said in the last edit the problem was `user: { $first: '$user' }` but I don't really know how and why.